# read single node xml in java

Tags: java, xml

I am doing request to remote server and get this  xml response with single  string tag.

```
<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">1405</string>
```

How can I get value(1405) of string tag?

I tried this, but it does not work:

```
NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName("string");    
Node n = nl.item(0);   
String root = n.getNodeValue();
```

Comment: I have accpeted already.

Comment: No, you haven't. None of your 26 questions have yet to be marked as accepted.

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to specify XML namespace in your Java code. The reason why you get null instead of "1045" is that because n.getNodeValue() actually returns value of element node (org.w3c.dom.Element), not inner text node (org.w3c.dom.Text).

```
String root = n.getTextContent();
String root = n.getFirstChild().getNodeValue(); // in some environments safer way
```

Answer (score 2):

There are options other than using DOM:

**XPath - javax.xml.path (Available as part of Java SE 5)**

An example:

```
import java.io.StringReader;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String xml = "<car><manufacturer>toyota</manufacturer></car>";
        String xpath = "/car/manufacturer";
        XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
        assertEquals("toyota",xPath.evaluate(xpath, new InputSource(new StringReader(xml))));
    }

}
```

**JAXB - javax.xml.bind (Available as part of Java SE 6)**

***Domain Object***

```
package com.example;

import javax.xml.bind.annotations.*;

@XmlRootElement(name="string", namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/")
public class StringValue {

    private String value;

    @XmlValue
    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

}
```

***Demo***

```
package com.example;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(StringValue.class);
        Unmarshaller u = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        StringValue stringValue = (StringValue) u.unmarshal(xml);
        System.out.println(stringValue.getValue());

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

That is because the text “1405” is not the value of the <string> tag’s element. It is instead the value of a text node that is a direct child of the <string> tag’s element. See the table [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html).